# Clicking on Jenkins Job Config History badge gives 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, config, history, jobs, badge

I'm using Jenkins core version - 1.545 and facing an issue with the Job Config history plugin (v2.9, but I did try 2.8 as well). On restarting Jenkins I can see this warning,

```
*Aug 13, 2015 2:10:52 AM hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz scout
WARNING: **Failed to scout hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryActionFactory
java.lang.InstantiationException: /kohls/prop/kcm/jenkins-home/plugins/jobConfigHistory/WEB-INF/lib/jobConfigHistory.jar might need to be rebuilt: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryActionFactory**
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:144)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:666)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:310)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:138)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:309)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:295)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:248)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:138)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getDescriptorByType(Jenkins.java:1185)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.BuildSelectorParameter.initAliases(BuildSelectorParameter.java:99)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifactPlugin.postInitialize(CopyArtifactPlugin.java:35)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$2.run(PluginManager.java:373)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:897)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryActionFactory
    at hudson.PluginManager$UberClassLoader.findClass(PluginManager.java:984)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at net.java.sezpoz.IndexItem.element(IndexItem.java:134)
    ... 21 more*
```

I did try uninstalling the plugin and re-installing it, but no luck. The problem is if I click on the Jobconfig history badge that appears next to each build which had config changes it gives me a 404.

```
**HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.63**
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here?